# Converting Span to Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, web-applications

I am developing web app, I have such a requirement that whenever user click on `text` inside `span` i need `convert` it into `input field` and `on blur` i need to `convert it back` to span again. So i am using following script in one of my jsp page.

Java Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function covertSpan(id){

    $('#'+id).click(function() {
        var input = $("<input>", { val: $(this).text(),
                                   type: "text" });
        $(this).replaceWith(input);
        input.select();   
    }); 

      $('input').live('blur', function () {
            var span=$("<span>", {text:$(this).val()});
            $(this).replaceWith(span);

      });         
}
```

JSP Code:

```
<span id="loadNumId" onmouseover="javascript:covertSpan(this.id);">5566</span>
```

Now my problem is, everything works fine only for the first time. I mean whenever i click on the text inside span for the `first time` it converts into input field and again `onblur` it coverts back from input field to normal text. But if try once again to do so it won't work. Whats wrong with above script?

Comment: There are also jQuery Plugins for "Edit in Place":

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708801/whats-the-best-edit-in-place-plugin-for-jquery

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Would be good to change your dom structure to something like this (note that the span and the input are side by side and within a shared parent `.inputSwitch`

```
<div class="inputSwitch">
First Name: <span>John</span><input />
</div>
<div class="inputSwitch">
Last Name: <span>Doe</span><input />
</div>
```

Then we can do our JS like this, it will support selecting all on focus and tabbing to get to the next/previous span/input: http://jsfiddle.net/x33gz6z9/

```
var $inputSwitches = $(".inputSwitch"),
  $inputs = $inputSwitches.find("input"),
  $spans = $inputSwitches.find("span");
$spans.on("click", function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.hide().siblings("input").show().focus().select();
}).each( function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.text($this.siblings("input").val());
});
$inputs.on("blur", function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.hide().siblings("span").text($this.val()).show();
}).on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 9) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.shiftKey) {
      $(this).blur().parent().prevAll($inputSwitches).first().find($spans).click();
    } else {
      $(this).blur().parent().nextAll($inputSwitches).first().find($spans).click();
    }
  }
}).hide();
```

Comment: I have a problem now,after updating my jquery version the above code is not working.

Comment: What version? I just ran it in 2.0 and 2.x (edge) and it worked fine. What is happening? Any errors showing in console?

Answer (score 2):

I understand you think that element replacement is a nice thing, however, I would use a prompt to get the text. Why? It is a lot easier and actually a bit prettier for the user as well. If you are curious on how to do it, I show you.

html:

```
<span class='editable'>foobar</span>
```

js:

```
$(function()
{
  $('span.editable').click(function()
  {
    var span = $(this);
    var text = span.text();

    var new_text = prompt("Change value", text);

    if (new_text != null)
      span.text(new_text);
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qJxhV/1/

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to change your click handler to use `live()` as well. You should take note, though, that `live()` has been deprecated for quite a while now. You should be using [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in both cases instead.

Secondly, when you replace the input with the span, you don't give the element an id. Therefore, the element no longer matches the selector for your click handler.

Personally, I would take a different (and simpler) approach completely. I would have both the span and in the input in my markup side by side. One would be hidden while the other is shown. This would give you less chance to make mistakes when trying to recreate DOM elements and improve performance since you won't constantly be adding/removing elements from the DOM.

Comment: "Therefore, the element no longer matches the selector for your click handler" - which click handler? `covertSpan` is called only once and I see no other click handler attachment.

Comment: Not a bad idea! I have to try it some time.

Answer (score 0):

A more generic version of [smerny's excellent answer](/a/16374275/5031672) with id's can be made by slightly altering two lines: 
`$input.attr("ID", "loadNum");` becomes `$input.attr("ID", $(this).attr("ID"));` -- this way, it simply takes the current id, and keeps it, whatever it is.

Similarly, 
`$span.attr("ID", "loadNum");` becomes `$span.attr("ID", $(this).attr("ID"));`

This simply allows the functions to be applied to any div. With two similar lines added, both id and class work fine. See [example](https://jsfiddle.net/zblackwo/2D9FW/94/).

Answer (score 0):

I have done little change in code, By using this input type cant be blank, it will back to its real value.

```
 var switchToInput = function () {
        var $input = $("<input>", {
            val: $(this).text(),
            type: "text",
            rel : jQuery(this).text(),
        });
        $input.addClass("loadNum");
        $(this).replaceWith($input);
        $input.on("blur", switchToSpan);
        $input.select();
    };
    var switchToSpan = function () {
            if(jQuery(this).val()){
                        var $text = jQuery(this).val();
                } else {
                      var $text = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
                }
        var $span = $("<span>", {
            text: $text,
        });
        $span.addClass("loadNum");
        $(this).replaceWith($span);
        $span.on("click", switchToInput);
    }
    $(".loadNum").on("click", switchToInput);
```

jsFiddle:- https://jsfiddle.net/svsp3wqL/